# AngularJS Get Filtered Scope onClick

Tags: angularjs

I want to get an alert button for showing the filtered object of my filtered data in Angular. 
In my HTML template i can get the object i want with:  `{{(portals|myFilter:or| filter:search )}}`

I have my button :

```
<a ng-href='#here' ng-click='go()' >click me</a>
```

and my function `go()` is already working but now I need the object wich I can call with : `{{(portals|myFilter:or| filter:search )}}` in my `go()` function... Any idea?

I have already tried to write the object in the button but I didnt even believed that this is too easy. There must be a way to get the same object in my controller ?

Comment: Solved Thanks to Mathias F 

added to go function 

        go(or,search)

after that i modified my go function with :

        var myRedObjects = $filter('myFilter')($scope.portals, or);
        var myRedObjects = $filter('filter')(myRedObjects, search);

now i got it thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a ng-href='#here' ng-click='go(myFilter,search)' >click me</a>
```

Comment: ok thats on step closer: 

        go(or,search)

after that i modified my go function with :

        var myRedObjects = $filter('myFilter')($scope.portals, or);
        var myRedObjects = $filter('filter')(myRedObjects, search);

now i got it thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can assign filteredItems with the following syntax:

```
{{filteredItem = (portals|myFilter:or| filter:search )}}
<a ng-href='#here' ng-click='go(filteredItem)' >click me</a>
```

You can check the below snippet for an example.

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.items = ["apple", "banana", "orange"];
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input ng-model="query"/>
    {{filteredItems = (items | filter:query)}}
    <div>Filtered Items: {{filteredItems}}<div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```